# Processing - Color loop

Tags: java, colors, processing, rgb

I'm trying to create a window, where when you click once a loop of color changing will happen:

Code:

```
package declaringvariables;

import processing.core.PApplet;


public class DeclaringVariables extends PApplet {

    public void setup() {

        width = 800;
        height = 600;
        size(width,height);
    }

    boolean down = false;
    float R = 255;
    float G = 255;
    float B = 0;
    float incremento = +1;
    float mincol = 0, maxcol = 255;

    public void draw() {

        background (1,255,1);

        if(down) {
            println("\nFramecount: "+frameCount);
            println("The current framerate is: "+frameRate);
            background(R,G,B);
            R += incremento;
            if (R > maxcol) incremento = -1;
            else if (R > mincol) incremento = random(2);
                B += incremento;
            if (B > maxcol) incremento = -1;
            else if (B < mincol) incremento = +5;
                G += incremento;
            if (G > maxcol) incremento = -1;
            else if (G < mincol) incremento = +10;
            frameRate(150);
            }
        }


    public void mousePressed() {
        down = true;
    }
}
```

As it is now it kind of works, I click it starts to change color until it gets green (1,255,1)RGB, then it stops. I need it to loop, so it's a constant changing background.

I thought about making some kind of "if statement", which resets the background when it turns to green. Also concidered a while loop, but it both dropped my framerate and didn't make it work.

End of the line, I want my if(down = true) statement to repeat it self once clicked.

Thank you in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are few things that could improve, independent of your main colour interpolation issue:

1. Calling `size(800,600);` is better instead of accessing `width,height` directly, prior to calling `size()` (which does quite a few things behind the scene)
2. You can set the frameRate once in `setup()`, rather than setting it over and over again in `draw()`
3. If values don't behave the way you expect, it's a good idea to print them to the console or display them on screen so you can observe how they behave

Closer related to your issue:

1. You're using a single increment for 3 values, but want 3 values to increment independently: you should use 3 increment variables to keep each colour channel value independent
2. You should check and adjust the increment *before* applying it to a colour channel.

Here are the three points above in code:

```
public void setup() {

    size(800,600);
}

boolean down = false;
float R = 255;
float G = 255;
float B = 0;
float incrementoR = +1;
float incrementoG = +1;
float incrementoB = +1;
float mincol = 0, maxcol = 255;

public void draw() {

    background (1,255,1);

    if(down) {

        println("\nFramecount: "+frameCount);
        println("The current framerate is: "+frameRate);
        background(R,G,B);
        R += incrementoR;
        if (R > maxcol) incrementoR = -1;
        else if (R > mincol) incrementoR = random(2);
            B += incrementoB;
        if (B > maxcol) incrementoG = -1;
        else if (B < mincol) incrementoG = +5;
            G += incrementoG;
        if (G > maxcol) incrementoB = -1;
        else if (G < mincol) incrementoB = +10;
        frameRate(150);
        }

     fill(127);   
     text("R:"+(int)R+"\tG:"+(int)G+"\tB:"+(int)B,15,15);

    }


public void mousePressed() {
    down = true;
}
```

You will notice values go outside of the 0-255 range pretty fast. 
Here's the code tweaked to update increments first, then the values.
Also, this is done prior to drawing, otherwise you'll always be drawing the previous R,G,B values:

```
public void setup() {

  size(800,600);
  frameRate(150);

}

boolean down = false;
float R = 255;
float G = 255;
float B = 0;
float incrementoR = +1;
float incrementoG = +1;
float incrementoB = +1;
float mincol = 0, maxcol = 255;

public void draw() {

    background (1,255,1);

    if(down) {

        //update increments prior to applying them
        if(R > maxcol) incrementoR = -1;
        if(R < mincol) incrementoR = random(2);

        if(G > maxcol) incrementoG = -1;  
        if(G < mincol) incrementoG = +5;

        if(B > maxcol) incrementoB = -1; 
        if(B < mincol) incrementoB = +10;

        //apply increments
        R += incrementoR;
        G += incrementoG;
        B += incrementoB;

        println("\nFramecount: "+frameCount);
        println("The current framerate is: "+frameRate);
        background(R,G,B);
        }

     fill(127);   
     text("R:"+(int)R+"\tG:"+(int)G+"\tB:"+(int)B,15,15);

    }


public void mousePressed() {
    down = true;
}
```

If you want to play with colour more, you should also checkout [lerpColor()](http://processing.org/reference/lerpColor_.html) and [colorMode()](https://processing.org/reference/colorMode_.html), they're fun to play with.

Answer (score 1):

First of all: do you really mean `if(down = true)` ? This will assign true to down, not only test if it is true. I suggest you use `if(down)` instead.

In order to loop the colors, you could use a modulo (%). That way, you start from 0 once you get over 255.

Comment: Used if (down) at origin, forgot to put it back after messing around in the code. So in what manner do I use modulo

Comment: I am not sure what your code in the if(down) is doing/supposed to do. Can you elaborate please?

Comment: When the window is clicked, my background smoothly change colors. So the code is checking if R/G/B is above/below my max and minimum color. And then it adjusts. Creating a smooth transition

Comment: So I tried messing a little around with this, you want me to create a new void named next, or am I misunderstanding.

Comment: Yes, that way you don't have everything in one method (draw). A debug output of the values of r, g and b would also help you. They might not be what you expect.